# The measure of a (not necessarily disjoint) union

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measurable space. Prove that, for $A,B \in \Sigma$, $\mu(A) + \mu(B) = \mu(A \cup B) + \mu(A \cap B)$.

Sorry that I don't have many thoughts to add here, but I really don't know where to get started with this proof. Obviously this reduces to the countable additivity axiom when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so perhaps I need to be clever with symmetric differences and make use of that?

Please, only give hints, not full solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider
$$
A \cup (B-A\cap B)=A\cup B\quad\text{and }\quad A \cap (B-A\cap B)=\varnothing
$$
And
$$
(B-A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B)=B \quad\text{and }\quad (B-A\cap B)\cap (A\cap B)=\varnothing
$$

Comment: Thanks for this, managed to get it from here :)

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could give you a more subtle hint.

$$
A\cup B=[A\setminus (A\cap B)]\cup [B\setminus (A\cap B)]\cup (A\cap B). 
$$

Comment: Did you mean $A \cap B$ instead of that last $A \cup B$? Also, no problem; this still leaves plenty for me to figure out and/or play with, or at least, it seems that way :)

Comment: Yes indeed. $\ $